# How can I get the parent of an instance

Tags: javascript, oop

in my project I need to get the instance of the object that created another instance of a second object.

I bypassed the problem by sending the instance in the constructor of the second object, but I'm looking for a better solution

For example:

*First Object (the parent)*

```
    function AnimalsList()
    {
            var _list = new Array();
            this.List = _list;

            this.Add = function(name)
            {
                    _list.push(new Animal(name),this);
            }
    }
```

*Second Object (the child)*

```
    function Animal(name, parent)
    {
            this.Name = name;

            this.GetList = function()
            {
                    return parent
            }
    }
```

I know that in this case the "GetList" function was more logical included in the first object, but is just an example.

I tried to use `this.constructor` but returns the function and not the instance

I hope I have explained the problem well, I have a bad English!

thanks

Comment: Please provide a fiddle

Comment: What you have looks fine. Other solutions would depend of what and you need the parent for, and where.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just this:

```
function Animal(name, parent)
{
        this.Name = name;
        this.List = parent;
}
```

?

And I suspect that you wanted to write:

```
_list.push(new Animal(name,this));
```

rather than what you have there.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get this information via the function's [caller property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller#Example%3a_Checking_the_value_of_a_function.27s_caller_property).  It's not part of the ECMAScript standard but it is supported by all major browsers.

However, it is probably a better idea to continue doing it the way you are doing it now.  Your current method is more explicit and doesn't tie the program's function call structure directly to the properties of the animal object, which is probably a better model.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
function AnimalsList()
{
        var _list = new Array();
        this.List = _list;

        function getList() { return _list; } 

        this.Add = function(name)
        {
           var obj = { Name:name, GetList:getList };
           _list.push(obj);
           return obj;
        }
}
```

then?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend don't use a constructor with a reference on the parent list like this: `Animal(name, parent)`. Because an animal should not know about List. This is a deal of List to say an animal "*Hey, dude! You are in my collection.*" So, my minor modifications:

```
function Animals()
{
    var __list = new Array();

    this.List = __list;

    this.Create = function(name){
        return this.Add(new Animal(name));
    }

    this.Add = function(animal){
        animal.__parent= this;
        __list.push(animal);
        return animal;
    }

    Animals.Parent = function(animal){
        return animal.__parent;
    }
}

function Animal(name)
{
    this.Name = name;
}
```

**Example:**

```
var animalsLikeDogs = new Animals();
var dog = animalsLikeDogs.Create("dog");

var animalsLikeCats = new Animals();
var cat = animalsLikeCats.Create("cat");

Animals.Parent(dog);
Animals.Parent(cat);
```

Comment: Since `Animal` instances have a `Parent` property, shouldn't the constructor be the place wher it is set? What you are actually suggesting conceptually is to remove the property altogether.

Comment: Actually you can remove the Parent property. I will do this changes right now.

Comment: @JanDvorak, do you like it now?

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, the AnimalList is an aggregator, not the parent of Animal objects. Your code seems fine, but I would suggest you to change the variable name from 'parent' to 'aggregator'.